# View instance without button click in android

Tags: java, android, vidyo

I am using vidyo to implement video calls in my android app.
How do I create a view instance on loading a new intent?

I have a button, and on clicking it I am able to do required action.
It is defined as such.

```
public void Start(View v){
   vc = new Connector(videoFrame, Connector.ConnectorViewStyle.VIDYO_CONNECTORVIEWSTYLE_Default,
                16, "warning all@VidyoConnector info@VidyoClient", "", 0);
   vc.showViewAt(videoFrame, 0, 0, videoFrame.getWidth(), videoFrame.getHeight());
   }
```

But now, I want the same action to be performed without button click.

It should happen in onCreate(), but this is failing. I am unable to view my camera preview. What else can be done?

Comment: please post the crash log when it is failing.

Comment: app is not crashed. im unable to view the preview when I add the same code within onCreate().

Comment: try to add on onResume

Comment: Try the same code `onStart()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because your videoFrame is not layouted yet.
You need to make sure that the view finished layouting before using `getWidth` and `getHeight` methods, to do that you might use e.g. OnglobalLayoutListener.

```
videoFrame.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
// YOUR CODE GOES HERE
videoFrame.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting a complete blank screen with this. App is not crashing but preview isnt opening either

Comment: There might be a problem rendering your video frame, do you see any warnings ?

Comment: Tried it again, screen does not open at once, it is shrinking and growing till the connection is established.

Comment: oops forgot to mention that you should unRegister the listener after the first call, i updated the answer